# I am having a difficulty of understanding interfaces in Solidity. What am I missing?

Tags: interface, ethereum, solidity

I came from Java OOP background and understand interfaces.

Currently working on a simple budgeting app (https://github.com/compound-developers/compound-supply-examples) that takes ETH or Stablecoin and put in in Compound and earn interest.

My confusion is how Solidity Interfaces are used. I came from OOP (Java) background and very familiar with interfaces.

So in this code(`MyContracts.sol`) you can see that there is a `mint()` function in the interface. However, there is no implementation for it but you can see that it's used here `uint mintResult = cToken.mint(_numTokensToSupply);` without any implementation.

Can anyone shade some lights on how interface functions are used without implementations ? When you call **mint** in this case, which code is actually being executed ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe I got the main issue that was confusing to me.

So if you come from OOP background this what we know about interfaces:

```
interface IERC20 { 
   function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
}

contract XYZ is IERC20 {
// then implement totalSupply here 
function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {
// implementiation goes here. 
address public add='0x123...4'
}
```

So at this point you can call XYZ's `totalSupply()` and you should be fine.

However, there is another way of using interfaces in Solidity. I will take this code from compound protocol as an example (https://github.com/compound-developers/compound-supply-examples)

If you see `MyContracts.sol`, it has the following interface:

```
interface CEth {
    function mint() external payable;

    function exchangeRateCurrent() external returns (uint256);

    function supplyRatePerBlock() external returns (uint256);

    function redeem(uint) external returns (uint);

    function redeemUnderlying(uint) external returns (uint);
}
```

However, there is no place in our contract that uses the keyword **IS** and implements any of the methods. So you might ask how is our interface being used ?

Now let's go back to `MyContract` contract in `MyContracts.sol` file and see this code under `supplyEthToCompound` function:

```
CEth cToken = CEth(_cEtherContract);
```

Here we are providing CEth interface with a contract address of Compound (i.e `_cEtherContract` and the contract at that address has a **mint()** function.)

When you call  `cToken.exchangeRateCurrent();` on the next line, what happens is we are basically calling a function **exchangeRateCurrent** on Compound Contract.

At first it seems like **exchangeRateCurrent** has no implementation in the file we are calling it but the implementation resides at **_cEtherContract** address.

I hope this clears the confusion especially if you come from traditional OOP background.

Feel free to point out anything that is misleading in my answer.

Comment: Hey, 
thank you very much for your explanation. It is very helpful.
I would like to ask you (and I am sorry in advance for a silly question, but I am really new to OOP):
In the code, you defined the implementation of the totalSupply() function in the contract. My question is. Why would I define the totalSupply() without implementation in interface if I subsequently define the function again in the contract? What for is the interface then? 
PS if you have a great source to study in order to understand, please, I would love to dive into it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I still don't get it, where is the Compound contract defined and the implementation for the exchangeRateCurrent() function?

Answer (score 0):

`interface` is used for type casting. [from this contract](https://github.com/tinchoabbate/damn-vulnerable-defi/blob/master/contracts/unstoppable/UnstoppableLender.sol)

```
interface IReceiver {
    function receiveTokens(address tokenAddress, uint256 amount) external;
}
```

inside contract

```
contract UnstoppableLender is ReentrancyGuard {
    .....
    function flashLoan(uint256 borrowAmount) external nonReentrant {
        require(borrowAmount > 0, "Must borrow at least one token");
        uint256 balanceBefore = damnValuableToken.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(balanceBefore >= borrowAmount, "Not enough tokens in pool");
        assert(poolBalance == balanceBefore);
        damnValuableToken.transfer(msg.sender, borrowAmount);

        // that means msg.sender has receiveTokens functionality
        // we are making sure that who ever is calling this function, has this method implemented
        // we can conclude that ms.sender is a contract address
        IReceiver(msg.sender).receiveTokens(
            address(damnValuableToken),
            borrowAmount
        );
      .......
}
```

`msg.sender` is the address that calling `flashLoan` function. By casting with the `IReceiver` interface we are saying that whichever contract address is calling `flashLoan` function must have it is own `receiveTokens` function implemented.

If you look at the [contract that](https://github.com/tinchoabbate/damn-vulnerable-defi/blob/master/contracts/unstoppable/ReceiverUnstoppable.sol)  calling the `flashLoan` function, in fact has `receiveTokens`

```
function receiveTokens(address tokenAddress, uint256 amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == address(pool), "Sender must be pool");
        // Return all tokens to the pool
        require(IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(msg.sender, amount), "Transfer of tokens failed");
    }
```